# Application killed while performing onPause(). Any tips on how to handle such a case?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

My application saves its current image data to file during `onPause()` to persist it from session to session.
However, I noticed that if I turn off the device when the app is in the foreground, the app is paused and restarted multiple times in quick succession before finally being killed in the middle of writing to file in `onPause()`.

In `onPause()`, I ask and wait for the image data from the renderer thread of a `GLSurfaceView` by calling `gLSurfaceView.queueEvent()` with a `FutureTask` and then calling `futureTask.get()`. Then, after I get the data, I call `gLSurfaceView.onPause()` and then write the data to a file on external storage. After that I call `super.onPause()`.

However, it looks like `onPause()` is interrupted while writing to the external storage, so that when the app is restarted next, it reports `java.io.EOFException` when trying to read the saved data.

I logged what happens when I turn off the device. Here is the trace:

```
05-17 16:03:47.405: V/App(4633): onPause called
05-17 16:03:47.405: V/App(4633): Get data from render thread.
05-17 16:03:47.670: V/App(4633): Got data from render thread.
05-17 16:03:47.855: V/App(4633): Save image start
05-17 16:03:48.265: V/App(4633): Image saved!
05-17 16:03:48.265: V/App(4633): super.onPause()
05-17 16:03:48.270: V/App(4633): onPause finished
05-17 16:03:48.270: V/App(4633): onSaveInstanceState()
05-17 16:03:48.315: V/App(4633): onCreate()
05-17 16:03:48.345: V/App(4633): restoreState() with bundle
05-17 16:03:48.345: V/App(4633): Start read image.
05-17 16:03:49.055: V/App(4633): Image read
05-17 16:03:49.715: V/App(4633): onResume()
05-17 16:03:51.595: V/App(4633): onPause called
05-17 16:03:51.595: V/App(4633): Get data from render thread.
05-17 16:03:51.770: V/App(4633): Got data from render thread.
05-17 16:03:51.910: V/App(4633): Save image start
05-17 16:03:52.580: V/App(4633): Image saved!
05-17 16:03:52.580: V/App(4633): super.onPause()
05-17 16:03:52.580: V/App(4633): onPause finished
05-17 16:03:52.585: V/App(4633): onSaveInstanceState()
05-17 16:03:53.795: V/App(4633): onResume()
05-17 16:03:53.805: V/App(4633): onPause called
05-17 16:03:53.805: V/App(4633): Get data from render thread.
05-17 16:03:54.205: V/App(4633): Got data from render thread.
05-17 16:03:54.520: V/App(4633): Save image start
```

After that, the device shuts down, or at least the logging stops.

Presumably, the data is saved correctly the first 2 times, but it gets thrashed on the 3rd time since the app doesn't finish writing to the file.

I am thinking of implementing a double buffer solution where I would alternate the buffer where I write the data and save a reference to which buffer contains the latest data after writing it successfully. But I figure there must be a simpler way.

Any advice on how to avoid / work around this problem?

Note: Since the whole onPause() takes close to 1 second, I also tried doing the sequence [Read from GLSurfaceView, pause GLSurfaceView and save to file] in a background thread, but then I also get into situations where onCreate() tries to read the image data while the background thread is still writing it, which obviously also causes an error.

Comment: Shouldn't you be saving data in `onSaveInstanceState()`? So that when your activities are killed by Android OS, you get it back in `onCreate()` while recreating the activity?

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState()` is not a good option because I need to persist the data from one instance to another. For example, if the user shuts down the app with he Back button, `onSaveInstanceState` won't be called, but I still need to save the image.

Comment: I think in your 2nd and 3rd call the surface is not created, if you track the surface created event, then you can avoid saving in 2nd and 3rd calls.

Comment: Amongst other things, you probably want to avoid saving again when there has been no real "progress" or even meaningful elapsed time since the previous save.  Also, the external storage may not be a great place to save during a shutdown, as it might (?) be unmounted comparatively early, at which point apps holding fd's to it are killed.

Comment: @SudarNimalan I thought you had it, but I added code to check surface creation and destruction. Turns out it is destroyed after the first `onPause()`, but recreated after the first `onResume()` and never destroyed again. Too bad that doesn't work :(

Comment: I am sorry, We too had same issue even in locking/unlocking in some devices, we could manage to resolve in this and for some other devices we wanted to track the onWindowFocusChanged call. On our experience in your 2nd and 3rd calls the onWindowFocusChanged is not  called. So we track both onResume and onWindowFocusChanged calls if both called only we assume that surface has some buffer to save. (note that onResume and onWindowFocusChanged will not call in any order so we keep a int flag and add (bit or) 1 in onResume and 2 in onWindowFocusChanged and check for 3 and clear in onPause)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you by any chance saving the image in the UI thread, just right during your onPause() call? If yes, you should move the image saving part into the `AsyncTask` and provide some kind of boolean flag or mutex to prevent similar AsyncTasks from being started while the previous image is still being saved or when it's already saved.

Be careful with using contexts and internal class data just in case your `AsyncTask` outlives your other classes and make sure it does not touch anything that does not belong to it.

Comment: Yes, that's was I was doing initially (see the Note in my original post), but the system creates a new process (call to `onCreate()`) which tries to read the data while the previous process is still writing to it, so I don't know I how could share a flag or mutex between 2 different processes.

Comment: If you want to avoid other processes reading your file while you're writing it, you might create a temporary file with a random name, write your data and only then rename it to the proper name, known to the other parts of your program.

Comment: Right, this is pretty much the double buffer solution I suggested in my original post. But I am hoping there is a simpler, cleaner way of doing things.